# Passing a class property to a method C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iqueryable

I am trying to create a sorting method that passes a class property to sort by. I am using ASP  .NET and MVC so the class i am referring to is actually a  model. The issue is that I keep getting an error that states:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Func`2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}
```

Here is my method:

```
    public IQueryable<AP_Tasks> GetOrderedList(IQueryable<AP_Tasks> tasks, Func<AP_Tasks, IComparable> prop, string previousSort, string currentSort, int currentCount)
    {
        if (previousSort == null)
        {
            tasks = tasks.OrderBy(x => x.TaskDate);
            return tasks;
        }
        if (previousSort == currentSort)
        {
            if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
                tasks = tasks.OrderByDescending(x => prop);
            else
            {
                tasks = tasks.OrderBy(x => x.TaskDate);
            }
        }
        return tasks;
    }
```

Here is my call:

```
            case "TaskID":
                query = GetOrderedList(query, x => x.TaskID, previousOrder, sortOrder, currentCount);
                break;
            case "TaskDate":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(t => t.TaskDate);
                break;
```

TaskID is my new call. If the case was TaskDate it would work but since there are many cases I would like to have a method do it for me to reduce redundancy.

UPDATED CODE

```
    public IQueryable<AP_Tasks> GetOrderedList(IQueryable<AP_Tasks> tasks, Func<AP_Tasks, IComparable> prop, string previousSort, string currentSort, int currentCount)
    {

        if (previousSort == null)
        {
            tasks = tasks.OrderBy(x => x.TaskDate);
            return tasks;
        }
        if (previousSort == currentSort)
        {
            if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
                tasks = tasks.OrderByDescending(prop);
            else
            {
                tasks = tasks.OrderBy(prop);
            }
        }
        return tasks;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you've posted irrelevant code. Post the code in which line you get the error.

Comment: GetOrderedList() is where the issue is. When it reaches X => prop. That is where the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following two methods to order a property based on a string property name instead of a lambda:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByProperty<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName),
        parameter);
    return Queryable.OrderBy(query, (dynamic)selector);
}
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescendingProperty<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName),
        parameter);
    return Queryable.OrderByDescending(query, (dynamic)selector);
}
```

This allows you to simply pass in whatever string you had been switching on to the method and order on that without needing to cover every single case individually at compile time.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. Can you show me how to call it?

Comment: becauase it takes a string

Comment: @user3788671 You take your query, and you pass in the string that you already have with your property name, and then you're done.

Comment: @user3788671 Then you'll need to add the appropriate `using`, as you always do when you have that error.

Comment: sorry, there was a confliction between the axaj utilities. Ill try it now

Comment: Works like a champ. Thank you!